# Show meeting events on top of the work week grid

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

I have a meeting invite that is essentially me notifying co-workers that I'm OOO for a period.  However I want it to appear at the top of the work week grid so as not to clog their schedules.  I know that if an event is marked as all day it goes up there by default, but I've seen other events that are located in the same place without marking them as an all day event

The green events on this [image](http://files.itproportal.com/wp-content/uploads/photos/microsoft-outlook-2013-calendar_original.jpg) depict what I am looking for.  Note how they occur at the top of the grid and not during any specific time slots

Answer (score 0):

If you don't make it an all day event, you just make the meeting request a multi-day invite with a start and end time. Multi-day events are listed at the top even if they are not all day events.

[image]